# How to target the last element in a container with CSS while taking in account his order property?

Tags: html, css, sass

I was using the `:last-child` property to apply some css to an element.

But sometime I have to change the order of those elements through the flex `order` attribute.

Is it somehow possible to always target the "visually" last child?

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <h2>Bar</h2>
</div>
```

```scss
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  h1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  h2 {
    order: 0; 
  }
  :last-child {
     padding-bottom: 26px;
  }
}
```

This will add the padding to `h2` because this is the last child in the DOM.
But I would like to always select the "visually" last child.

#### Some context

I'm creating a card component, which may contain images, title, subtitle description, buttons, ... & I which to target some specific elements based on their order.

But those `order` may be added through iFrame from a parent website, this is the reason why I'm trying to change those base on their position within the container

I do try to simplify my question by removing some complexity, hope it helps

**Why padding-bottom on a child ?** Because, on this example, the `image` shouldn't have any padding, but this is the only element which won't have any padding, if moved to the bottom, I've planned to solve this by adding the `padding-bottom: 0 !important` to that specific element

Comment: _"Is it somehow possible to always target the "visually" last child?"_ - **no**: a CSS stylesheet can be thought-of as a _pure function_ that transforms the DOM into a visual presentation - there is no provision for _feedback_: that is: self-referential stylesheets.

Comment: ...however as you're seeing `order: 1` _anyway_, then it means _that you know_ what the visuall last element is anyway.

Comment: Also, what you've posted isn't CSS, it looks like SCSS/SASS...

Comment: @Dai Yes, it's scss, though it would be easier to read that way, sry.

About the order, I've added a bit of context to my question, but I do not know the order, while creating my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in `CSS`, Add the padding to the container itself if it's just a padding.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  h1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  h2 {
    order: 0; 
  }
}
```

Comment: The "I can't do that in css" seems to be the answer, I'll search for another solution, I could go with having the `padding-bottom` but not every element should have a padding at the bottom. I've added a bit of context to my question, maybe you have an Idea how I could solve this?